# Derivation of TD(0) with Gradient Correction (TDC)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference-methods, importance-sampling

I'm trying to understand the derivation of TDC from Sutton and Barto, but I'm stuck on the steps between lines 2 and 3. It seems that the importance sampling ratio just "disappears" between these two steps, but I'm not sure what the mathematical basis for that is.

[image: TDC]

Comment: Could be great, if you would add a reference to the book itself and page/chapter/formula that is causing the confusion.